# Freemarker: convert sting to list with split then iterate

Tags: freemarker

I need to iterate through a list made from the "split" built-in yet I haven't succeeded.

I have a  two lists of dates that share some of the same dates. using "seq_index_of" as a "Vlookup" i'm able to find the correlation and get the index of the dates that are in both lists. however, "seq_index_of" gives a string, number, boolean or date/time values output and not a sequence (for me to iterate).

I use "split" to turn the string into a sequence. split wont truly do the job, though.

````
first i use seq_index_of for the two lists:
this will give me the index of correlated dates.
<#assign result>
<#list list1 as L1> 
${list2?seq_index_of(L1)}
</#list>
</#assign>
---------------------------------------
next I iterate the result. for this, imagine "array" is the result from above:
ex 1. this does not work. cant iterate

<#assign array = "2020-10-02,2021-10-04,2022-10-04,2023-10-04" />
<#assign mappedArray_string = []>
<#list array?split(",") as item>
<#assign mappedArray_string += [item]>
</#list>

${"is_sequence: " + mappedArray_string?is_sequence?c}

<#--print the list-->
<#list mappedArray_string as m>
<#--i cant do ?string("MM/dd/yyyy") or ant other iteration
${m?string("MM/dd/yyyy")}
<#if m?has_next>${";"}<#else>${"and"}</#if>-->
<#with no iteration, this will work. not what i need-->
${m}
</#list>
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ex 2. - this works with a regular numerical list
<#assign array = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500] />
<#assign mappedArray_numbers = []>
<#list array as item>
<#assign mappedArray_numbers += [item]>
</#list>

${"is_sequence: " + mappedArray_numbers?is_sequence?c}

<#--print the list-->
<#list mappedArray_numbers as m>
${m?string("##0.0")}<#-- able to iterate-->
</#list>```

expected:
date1 ; date2 ; date3 and lastdate

error:
For "...(...)" callee: Expected a method, but this has evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar):
==> m?string  [in template "preview-template" at line 27, column 3]

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
 - Failed at: ${m?string("MM/dd/yyyy")}
````

Comment: `?seq_index_of` actually always gives a number, the index of the item found. Also, when you create `mappedArray_string`, you just copy `array`; I guess you meant to do something else. Also, "ex 1." won't work because the `mappedArray_string` items are already stings, and so `?string("...")` has nothing to format (a string is already as formatted as it can be).

Comment: Anyway, what exactly do you want to get as the output? The list of common dates?

Comment: well, I have 2 lists containing dates. I need to find the dates from list 1 that appear in list 2. then, take the index of those dates and insert them in list 3 to get : date1, date2, date3... and dateN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list the items of `list2` that also occur in `list1`, then do this (requires FreeMarker 2.3.29 because of `?filter`):

```
<#list list2?filter(it -> list1?seq_contains(it)) as d>
  ${d?string('MM/dd/yyyy')}
</#list>
```

Before 2.3.29:

```
<#list list2 as d>
  <#if list1?seq_contains(d)>
    ${d?string('MM/dd/yyyy')}
  </#if>
</#list>
```

Comment: Added example without using `?filter` (for pre-2.3.29).